# Checkbox behavior in Windows phone 8 like Email in phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I wanted to know is there any way I can achieve the same behavior of CheckBox we have in our windows phone outlook. In a listbox I have checkbox on every item but it should appear only when I touch and hold.

Please see the windows phone email program where your touch and hold in the left side and see all the checkboxes.

Thanks
Vinod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `MultiselectList` control, which is part of the [WP Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)...

[image: MultiselectList example from the WP Toolkit]

Here are a a couple of tutorials from GeekChamp to get you started:

1. [Windows Phone Toolkit MultiselectList in depth](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-toolkit-multiselectlist-in-depth--part1-key-concepts-and-api)
2. [How to get the Tapped Item in a MultiselectList control](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-get-the-tapped-item-in-a-multiselectlist-control)

I would also recommend downloading the source code for the WP Toolkit which contains a sample app that uses all the controls and features:

http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest